# Django: загрузка пути к файлу в поле базы данных

Tags: django

Хотелось как то к действующим записям в БД подгрузить файлы но не ввиде самого файла а только ссылки на него. Тоесть файл находиться на файл шаре и БД в поле models.Filefiekd() нужен только путь к этому файлу. Чтобы он не копировался при загрузуке в MEDIA_ROOT.
В детальной информации по записи class DetailView я добавил кнопку редактировать и хотелось бы чтобы с class UpdateView я смог загрузить этот файл но в БД сохранить только путь к нему не файл-шаре.

views.py

```
# Редактируем проект

class ProjectUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Project
    form_class = ProjectForm
    template_name = 'districtdb/edit_project.html'
    context_object_name = 'edit_project'
```

models.py

```
class Project(models.Model):
    num_internal = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Внутрений номер')
    type_doc = models.ForeignKey(Typedoc, on_delete=PROTECT, null=True, verbose_name='Тип документации')
    date_doc = models.DateField(auto_now=False, verbose_name='Дата внутренея')
    title = models.TextField(max_length=800, verbose_name='Наименование')
    num_goverment = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Внешний номер')
    date_goverment = models.DateField(auto_now=False, verbose_name='Дата внешняя')
    district = models.ForeignKey(District, on_delete=PROTECT, null=True, verbose_name='Район')
    pdf = models.FileField(upload_to='attachment/', default='none', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Проект'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Проекты'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('detail_project', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

edit-project.html

```
% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}{{ block.super }} :: Редактирование проекта{% endblock %}

{% block content%}

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-4 mb-md-5 text-center">
                <h4>Редактирование проекта</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="d-flex flex-column">
                    <form method="post" action="{% url 'edit_project' edit_project.pk %}">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {{ form.as_p }}

                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Сохранить</button>
                    </form>

                     <form action="{% url 'detail_project' edit_project.pk%}" class="mt-md-3">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Отмена</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Как можно реализовать данную задумку.

Comment: как вариант организовать отдельный класс/модель `File` с полем `    pdf = models.FileField(upload_to='attachment/', default='none', null=True, blank=True)`,   и полем project со связью ForeignKey к модели Project

Comment: ну так а файлы всёравно ж будут загружены в attachment/ а мне это не нужно.

Comment: а, не заметил ` к действующим записям в БД`, тогда можно написать файл миграции, выбрать нужные FileField у него есть url() https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.url 
и присвоить как нибудь к `pdf` для нужного обьекта, что то типа `pdf__url` но это не точно